# center in table

Tags: tables, luatex

I would like to `\center` the column name `CENTER`, many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    content...

\begin{table}[ph]

    \caption{Future research directions}

    \begin{centering}
        {\scriptsize{}}%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|}
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}Q.No.} &  {\centering\scriptsize{}CENTER} 

            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}1} & {\scriptsize{}LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT}

            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}2} & {\scriptsize{}LEFT} 
            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}3} & {\scriptsize{}LEFT} 

            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}4} & {\scriptsize{}LEFT}
            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}{\scriptsize\par}
        \par\end{centering}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `{\centering\scriptsize{}CENTER}` with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\scriptsize{}CENTER}`, or, if you load `makecell`, the simple command `\makecell\scriptsize{}CENTER}`.  Other remarks;: you can simply use the `\centering` directive inside `table` , and also `\scriptsize`just after entering the table environment  if all your cells contents are in scriptsize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bernard has already noted in a comment, if you want to override the default alignment option for a single cell, the best way to do so is employ a `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` directive. Here: Simply write `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{CENTER}`.

Your code contains a lot of features one would be tempted to call eccentricities. For instance, since it appears that the contents of every single cell should be rendered using the relative font size `\scriptsize`, it's much easier to do so via a single `\scriptsize` directive *before* the start of the `tabular` environment instead of populating each and every table cell with a `\scriptsize` directive.

Do please compare the code used to generate the following side by side tables. The one on the left employs your code; the one on the right is thoroughly simplified; plus, it has replaced `{\centering\scriptsize{}CENTER}` with `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{CENTER}`.

By the way, the instruction `{\scriptsize{}}` does *exactly nothing*. Did you maybe mean to write `{\scriptsize{\null}}`? Do also take note of the fact that `\centering` is a LaTeX command that doesn't take an argument, *not* a LaTeX environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\caption{Original form of table}
\begin{centering}
        {\scriptsize{\null}}%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|}
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}Q.No.} &  {\centering\scriptsize{}CENTER} 

            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}1} & {\scriptsize{}LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT}

            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}2} & {\scriptsize{}LEFT} 
            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}3} & {\scriptsize{}LEFT} 

            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
            {\scriptsize{}4} & {\scriptsize{}LEFT}
            \tabularnewline
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}{\scriptsize\par}
        \par\end{centering}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\caption{Revised \& simplified form}
\centering
\scriptsize
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} % to compensate for global '\scriptsize' setting
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
    \hline 
    Q.No. &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{CENTER} \\
    \hline 
    1 & LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT \\
    \hline 
    2 & LEFT \\
    \hline 
    3 & LEFT \\
    \hline 
    4 & LEFT \\
    \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, don't keep `\begin{centering}`, please!

Comment: @egreg - I kept it only in the first `minipage`, which deliberately doesn't touch the OP's crufty habits. Happily, the `minipage` on the right switches to `\centering`.